# NS change propagation

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I changed the NS of my domain to Google Cloud DNS but after 24 hours the domain is still unreachable. Using some DNS checker tools seems that some countries is resolving Google NS, some countries the old NS and some countries nothing.
Is it normal? I have to change hundreds of domains, i can't put everything offline :/

Thanks
Marco

Comment: You are offtopic here as your question is not related to programming, and in any forum if you gave your domain name or any useful detail (like how you test precisely) people could have helped you better.

Comment: What is the TTL for your NS records? You will have to wait that long. This question is asked over and over. Search Stackoverflow for answers.

Comment: 3600 ; refresh
900         ; retry
86400 ; expire
10800 ; minimum TTL

Answer (score 0):

DNS propagation usually takes maximum upto 48 hours. but generally providers like google takes less time.If still you are facing any issue you can ask support to check the about the timing.

Comment: Thanks svikramjeet, the weird thing is that the old NS are not resolved, they are under DDoS attck right now. The propagation issues could be relate to the DDoS?

Comment: There is not really propagation in the DNS even if everyone uses this term, as the information does not flow from top to bottom but each bottom cache refreshes its information when it needs it (end of TTL). Hence the 48 hours does not come for any operational consideration, and is just a ballpark figure to start being worried after.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: That's indeed true for general worldwide lookups, but OTOH, propagation does exist in the path from the registrar to the registry, from the registry's database to their authoritative servers (some DNS hosting providers reload their zones immediately after update, others do it as a hourly or quarter-hourly cronjob), and finally between authoritative servers (some immediately push updates to secondaries via DNS NOTIFY or rsync, while others rely on periodic refresh). I do vaguely remember some sysadmins complaining about a TLD being very slow at accepting authoritative updates.

Comment: There is no prooagation between registrars and registries they use a fully symchronous real time protocol called EPP. Then for internal registry operations systems can be configured out of band without DNS mechanisms hence almost real time too. Big TLDs provide near real time updates visibility, not considering caches of course